# arrange() not working for a certain variable?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
employees <- as_tibble(employeedata)
any(is.na(employees))
employeesA <- employees %>%
  select('First name','Last name','Gender',everything()) %>%
  filter(Salary > 70000)  %>%
  arrange(Gender,'Last name')
employeesA
```

Newbie here - I think this should be arranging by gender and then, within gender, by last name in ascending order, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything to the order of the last names at all. Advice appreciated! Thanks :) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hEMO.png)

Comment: Use backticks for non-standard column names, not quotes. `arrange(Gender, \`Last name\`)`. When you put it in quotes, it's just a string.

Comment: (`select()` is a little special in that it accepts string column names, but I'd recommend using backticks there too for consistency and enforcing a good habit)

Comment: LOL thank you!!! So easy :)